# Model Data passed from View to Controller is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a view which is being populated correctly from a Model. Here is a cutdown of the View:

```
@model PickardOrdering.Models.ExhibitionItemModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.AdditionalItem.Value, new { @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsItemSelected.Value)</td>
            <td>£&nbsp;@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ItemPrice)</td>
        </tr>
    }

<input type="submit" value="Save Items" />
```

When I post the data back to the controller, exhibitionitemmodel is null:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("CreateExhibitionItems")]
    public ActionResult CreateExhibitionItems(ExhibitionItemModel exhibitionitemmodel)
    {
        decimal decPrice;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<tblExhibitionItem> lstExhibitionItem = new List<tblExhibitionItem>();
            IEnumerable<ItemWrapper> lstItemWrapper = from objExhibitionItemModel in exhibitionitemmodel.Items
                                                                                                                select objExhibitionItemModel;
```

Here is the model class used:

```
namespace PickardOrdering.Models
{
    public class ItemWrapper : tblItem
    {
        public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public bool? IsItemSelected { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExhibitionItemModel
    {   
        public IEnumerable<ItemWrapper> Items { get; set; }
        public tblExhibition Exhibition { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblExhibitionItem> ExhibitionItems { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Any ideas why the model data is null?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a public parameterless constructor on every class you use in your model, including the enumerables and classes used by them.

Also, instantiate your included classes in the constructor.  The model binder will need an instance of the objects to fill in.  Example is below.  Do this to all classes used by your model.

```
public class ExhibitionItemModel
{   

    public ExhibitionItemModel(){
        Exhibition = new tblExhibition();
        ExhibitionItems = new List<tblExhibitonItem>();
        Items = new List<ItemWrapper>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ItemWrapper> Items { get; set; }
    public tblExhibition Exhibition { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblExhibitionItem> ExhibitionItems { get; set; }
}
```

Also, in your view, iterate your items using an index, not a foreach loop.  This is so the view will generated with names containing indexes that the model binder can understand.

Comment: I've made these changes and it's now looking a lot better. However, when I pass the data from the view back to the controller, I get the correct values for IsItemSelected and ItemPrice, but everything else is null. For instance, exhibitionitemmodel.Items.ID from my original post is set to 0, as if it is not getting populated.

Comment: Add a hidden field for the ID to your view, and for very other piece of data you want submitted.  You will only get values that are present in the form.

Answer (score 1):

To make life easy on yourself with the model binding, I'd
suggest making an EditorTemplate for your `ItemWrapper` class.

```
// Views/<WhateverYourControllerIsCalled>/EditorTemplates/ItemWrapper.cshtml

@model PickardOrdering.Models.ItemWrapper

<tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Code)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description)</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalItem.Value, new { @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsItemSelected.Value)</td>
        <td>&nbsp;@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ItemPrice)</td>
</tr>
```

And your main .cshtml becomes:

```
@model PickardOrdering.Models.ExhibitionItemModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateExhibitionItems", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{  
    <table>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items)
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Items" />
}
```

Using the EditorFor on your `Items` collection will render the
html in the format that the default binder is expecting when
binding to a list.  You could render the html manually using
an index and a for loop if you want finer control over it, 
but this way takes care of it for you.

And as a general tip that I find useful in these situations,
add a `FormCollection` parameter to the action method that is
receiving the post, and inspect this parameter during
debugging.  This helps to see what data is getting posted
from the form, and from there you can figure out why it
isn't being bound during model binding.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any form in your `CSHTML` you can use this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)
You must use this code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateExhibitionItems", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{  @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.AdditionalItem.Value, new { @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsItemSelected.Value)</td>
            <td>£&nbsp;@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ItemPrice)</td>
        </tr>
    }

<input type="submit" value="Save Items" />}
```